# Mouse wheel event over Raphael element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, raphael, mousewheel

I need to perform an action if someone uses the wheel when the mouse is positioned over a Raphael element.

I tried several methods but none of it worked. Can you point me in the right direction with an example?

Comment: Have you tried jQuery mouse wheel plugin?

Comment: I remember that I did but I'm not sure. Will try again and come back with a response.

Comment: Amar Palsapure, it worked, you should've add it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks. I was just trying to check. Anyways it worked for you that's great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See live demo at http://jsfiddle.net/qiao/6JJrz/6/ (try mouse wheel up and down on the circle)

I used jQuery.mousewheel plugin taken from https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel

EDITED: sorry, the original link was outdated, I fixed it now.

Comment: In your fiddle, you haven't used Raphael as a source at all, rendering the demo useless.

Comment: I used Raphael, please see the `Manage Resources` tab at the left panel.

Comment: The original link was outdated. It should be fine now.

Comment: I ended up using this plugin: http://www.ogonek.net/mousewheel/jquery-demo.html but I'll mark your solution as the right answer because it works. Thanks